# queryset.exists() doesn't work correctly or I don't understand something?

Tags: django

I don't understand is it normal or it's time to create new django's ticket?

```
In [17]: User.objects.filter(pk=0)
Out[17]: []

In [18]: User.objects.filter(pk=0).exists()
Out[18]: True
```

The exists() should return False result in this case, I think. This is revision 11653 (Development version)

I have related problem with unique validating of inlineformset and I found that the reason is queryset.exists() doesn't work correctly

Comment: That certainly doesn't look right. It is new in development, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug, that was fixed in [11654](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/11654) changeset

Answer (score 2):

You can use `User.objects.filter(pk=0).count()` to check if objects matching your filters exist